# NotEnoughKeys when deploying a txn (ReactJs/Typescript/Solana)

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, phantom

I have this code to transfer sol via a contract and via web3 in ReactJS -

```
const transferSol = async () => {

        if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();

             const programId = new PublicKey('7XyzLTMw7nBzoZnYoxauCzv11ruJee3HqjbxCyDfYb52'); //transfer sol
        const {
           context: { slot: minContextSlot },
            value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight }
        } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

        const fromPublicKey = new PublicKey(publicKey);
            const toPublicKey = new PublicKey(solAddr);

    const amount = new BN(solAmount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    const tx = new Transaction({
      recentBlockhash: blockhash,
      feePayer: publicKey,
    })
 //const blockhashInfo = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
// const tx = new Transaction({
//     ...blockhashInfo, feePayer: publicKey,
// });  

console.log("from pub key ", fromPublicKey.toString());
console.log("from pub key ", publicKey.toString());
console.log("to pub key ", toPublicKey.toString());
console.log("system programid ", SystemProgram.programId.toString());

      const transactionInstruction = 
         new TransactionInstruction({
        programId,
        keys: [
          {pubkey: publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
          {pubkey: toPublicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
          { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
          // add any additional keys here
        ],
        data: encodeIxData({ discriminator: 0, amount }), 
      }); 

      tx.add(transactionInstruction);
      const simResult = await connection.simulateTransaction(tx);
      console.log(simResult);     
console.log("tx === ", tx);
            const signature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection, {minContextSlot});
            const signatureResult = await connection.confirmTransaction({blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight, signature});
            console.log(" signature ", signature);
            setTxnSignature(signature);
}
```

This used via the browser with Phantom (chrome plugin). There is an error "NotEnoughKeys" -

```
from pub key  5EH28q5BE8GuYzUTyHuLEqzTJATxoshvJZkNWzxuLEsk
App.tsx:241 from pub key  5EH28q5BE8GuYzUTyHuLEqzTJATxoshvJZkNWzxuLEsk
App.tsx:242 to pub key  4dGDp3BuTaXiqJwwJhh9abUBBm6hMhRkidttr5N4Cemm
App.tsx:243 system programid  11111111111111111111111111111111
App.tsx:259 
{context: {…}, value: {…}}
context: {apiVersion: '1.14.13', slot: 198071637}
value: accounts: 
null err: {InstructionError: Array(2)}
logs: Array(3)
0
: 
"Program 7XyzLTMw7nBzoZnYoxauCzv11ruJee3HqjbxCyDfYb52 invoke [1]"
1
: 
"Program 7XyzLTMw7nBzoZnYoxauCzv11ruJee3HqjbxCyDfYb52 consumed 771 of 200000 compute units"
2
: 
"Program 7XyzLTMw7nBzoZnYoxauCzv11ruJee3HqjbxCyDfYb52 failed: insufficient account keys for instruction"
```

I checked the keys and the addr for the contract and they look to be OK. The Rust code for the contract -

```
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program::invoke,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction,
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub enum MyInstruction {
    Transfer { amount: u64 },
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    match MyInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)? {
        MyInstruction::Transfer { amount } => process_transfer(accounts, amount),
    }
}

fn process_transfer(accounts: &[AccountInfo], amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let from = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?.key;
    let to = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?.key;

    msg!("Transfering {} lamports from {} to {}", amount, from, to);

    let transfer_ix = system_instruction::transfer(from, to, amount);
    invoke(&transfer_ix, accounts)
}
```

Repo reference - https://github.com/zillerium/grizzlythonhackathon/blob/trevor/src/App.tsx
Deployed contract - https://explorer.solana.com/address/7XyzLTMw7nBzoZnYoxauCzv11ruJee3HqjbxCyDfYb52?cluster=devnet

It looks like the ReactJS using the Phantom wallet cannot execute the transaction. But the txn instruction has three keys coded and they all look ok.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to change that might fix this. First off, you'll need to declare `publicKey` as a signer in your transaction:

```
const transactionInstruction = 
         new TransactionInstruction({
        programId,
        keys: [
          {pubkey: publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},
          {pubkey: toPublicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
          { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
          // add any additional keys here
        ],
        data: encodeIxData({ discriminator: 0, amount }), 
      });
```

Next, when sending the accounts through `invoke`, be sure to not send in too much, just what's needed, ie:

```
fn process_transfer(accounts: &[AccountInfo], amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let from = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let to = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    msg!("Transfering {} lamports from {} to {}", amount, from.key, to.key);

    let transfer_ix = system_instruction::transfer(from.key, to.key, amount);
    invoke(&transfer_ix, &[from.clone(), to.clone()])
}
```

I hope that'll start to give a more helpful error message!